# Determining where someone touches on an image

Tags: android

This is a basic question that leads into others down the line.

I am looking at expanding my app to have a image of a target (3 circles) and I want the user to be able to touch on the target image where they hit. Then the app determines where the user clicked.

Not progressed down this line of development yet and do not know where the best place to start / learn. Has anyone got any tips / websites / examples that I can be pointed at to get the ball rolling

Thanks

UPDATED
What I am trying to do and I have no knowledge on where to start

- Draw a target on a canvas, 3 circles
- draw a cross depending where the user clicks on the target
- record a score depending on which circle the user clicked in

thanks

Comment: http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/ball-animation-example/

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) on your View. That will give you touch events and pass you the coordinates where the finger was at inside of a MotionEvent

Something like this ought to work:

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
        Log.i("TAG", "x: " + me.getX() + " y: " + me.getY());
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, as said above I really have no knowledge where to start withi this